# svg to pdf using inkscape gets out of memory exception

Tags: c#, pdf, svg, out-of-memory, inkscape

I have a page that uses inkscape so draw an svg image to a pdf file. It have worked before but now i changed the images on the site so now it doesn't. The code that fails is:

```
XImage image = XImage.FromFile(filePath);
```

and i get the

> System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory

My code looks like this:

```
    private static void DrawImage(XGraphics gfx, string filePath, double imageWidth, double imageHeight, double pagePadding, double beginDrawYPoint)
    {
        if (File.Exists(filePath) == false)
        {
            var f = File.Create(filePath);
        }
        XImage image = XImage.FromFile(filePath);
        gfx.DrawImage(image, pagePadding, pagePadding + beginDrawYPoint, imageWidth, imageHeight);
        gfx.Dispose();
    }
```

filePath variable looks like this: C:\Users\Daniel_2\Documents\Avtryck\Avtryck-Base.Prod\AvtryX.Web\Temp SVG Files\3ia45urj.5f5.pdf

Comment: Do you have other PDFs that work?  Is there something different about that PDF (i.e. very large file size)?  If you watch your memory usage, does it skyrocket?

Comment: How do i watch my memory usage? Nope they should be the same size. Don't know if they are though but the image is made the same way using kendoUI to draw graphs.

Comment: Agreeing with @JohnKoerner, the fact that it used to work fine, but now doesn't, makes it sound like a file-specific issue.

Comment: Im using this: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dataviz/pie-charts/index.html and it is made out of data from database. So the thing thats is new is that ive generated new piecharts using the new data from the database.